What Optimization Methods Are Suitable for Solving This Problem?
am new to the field of optimization and have encountered the following optimization problem. I am curious to know what type of optimization problem this is and what methods are appropriate for solving it.
$\begin{align}\min_{\mathbf{f}_{k}} \sum_{k=1}^{K}\frac{q_k}{f_k} \\
\text{s.t. } f_k &\geq t_k \quad \forall k \tag1\label1 \\
\sum_{k=1}^{K} f_k &= F \tag2\label2
\end{align}$
$q_{k}, t_k >0$.

Write it as an LP.

@copper.hat, can you show me how to do that and how to solve it after rewriting it?

Sorry, I commented too quickly, it is not an LP, at least not what I thought originally.

However, it is a convex problem (since the $q_k, f_k >0$) so is solvable by many methods. Projected gradients would be one approach (use a QP to solve the projection).

You might be able to do some case analysis and come up with an explicit solution.

I'm not certain that it applies in this problem but you may want to check out fractional programming. I used it a long time  ago so it's very fuzzy.

Here's something about it but your minimizing a function and they are finding minimizing points. There is a section on transforming it to a linear program so maybe copper.hat was not so mistaken regarding re-writing it. I don't know ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear-fractional_programming

Because of the constraint across $k$, the Charnes-Cooper transformation from linear-fractional programming to linear programming does not apply here, but you can instead transform to second-order cone programming as follows by introducing $x_k$ to represent $1/f_k$:
\begin{align}
& \text{minimize} & \sum_k q_k x_k \\
& \text{subject to} & f_k &\ge t_k && \text{for all $k$} \\
&& \sum_k f_k & = F \\
&& y &= \sqrt{2} \\
&& 2 f_k x_k &\ge y^2 && \text{for all $k$} \\
&& x_k &\ge 0 && \text{for all $k$} 
\end{align}
The fourth constraint, $2 f_k x_k \ge y^2$, is a rotated second-order cone constraint.  Everything else is linear.

RobPratt: Thanks for answer ( which I'll try to understand ) but, on my screen, your equations are coming out raw instead of in latex.

@markleeds Same for me, but everything displays correctly when I click Edit.

@RobPratt, It seems the labels make the error.

@Royi Thank you for the workaround.  I have used labels successfully in many other answers, and they are supposed to work.

@RobPratt, I agree. But maybe some configuration of MathJaX is changed over SE and makes this one fail. No idea...

@RobPratt and Royi: Thanks. it works now.
